# z-index doesn't work as I expected inside ion-slides

Tags: css, ionic-framework, slider, z-index, swiper.js

I have two sliders using `ion-slides` component and I've created a footer with two buttons (navigation buttons). Until there all right.

But... I have a form inside one of the sliders, so when I focus on a `input text` element, the `virtual keyboard`opens and moves the footer up, standing it in front of the form.

I know the `hide-on-keyboard-open` class, but this isn't inmediate (you can see how the footer is placed in front of the form for a couple of seconds), so I thought of use `z-index`

So, when the `footer` is moved upward, it is hidden under the form. But I can't get it work.

Maybe somebody can help me with this trouble?

My intention is that the green block is hidden under the blue block when they have contact... I've created a codepen to show this problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEBxRK?editors=1111

(since you can not open a virtual keyboard on a desktop computer, you can resize the height of the page to see that the `z-index` does not work)

Regards!

Comment: The `z-index` needs to be set to `.footerTest`'s sibling, the `<ion-slides options="sliderOptions" slider="slider">` element. Setting it to a child as you now did will not work

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Oh... So i cannot make what i describe my question? If I set z-index to ion-slides i cannot see the footer never.. btw could you transform your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index` needs to be set to the `.footerTest`'s sibling, the `<ion-slides options="sliderOptions" slider="slider">` element.

An option would be to move the `.footerTest` inside the slides.

Below sample shows how the `z-index` apply on elements and its children.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

```css
.dashed-box { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  border: dashed;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.gold-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: gold;
  width: 65%;
  left: 60px;
  height: 7em;
  top: 3em;
}
.green-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  left: 65%;
  top: -25px;
  height: 8em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.red-box { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: -4em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed-box">Dashed box
  <span class="gold-box">Gold box</span>
  <span class="green-box">Green box</span>
</div>
<div class="red-box">Red box</div>
```

But, if you omit the `z-index` on the `dashed-box` and use a negative value, as on the blue box, the blue goes beneath them all.

```css
.dashed-box { 
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 3; */
  border: dashed;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.gold-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: gold;
  width: 65%;
  left: 60px;
  height: 7em;
  top: 3em;
}
.green-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  left: 65%;
  top: -25px;
  height: 8em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.blue-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  top: -25px;
  height: 18em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.red-box { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: -4em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed-box">Dashed box
  <span class="gold-box">Gold box</span>
  <span class="green-box">Green box</span>
  <span class="blue-box">Blue box</span>
</div>
<div class="red-box">Red box</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May you update my codepen with this option?

Comment: @MartaGom I would be happy to do that, though I don't have time digging through the sliders script to see which elements gets z-index or not. I hope you understand that and that my answer helped you overcome the issue, even if you have to do the hard work yourself :)